# Send an array from Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, arrays, wsdl, ws

I am trying to consume with Python a WSDL created in PHP.

Fragment of the Service:

```
        require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
        function Sum($numbers){
            return array_sum($numbers);
        }
        ...
```

Client:

```
from suds.client import Client

    def wsarchivo():
        url = "http://localhost/PracticeSumArray/server.php?wsdl"
        client = Client(url)
        res = client.service.Sum([1,2,3])
        print(res)

    wsarchivo()
```

But when running it does not work to send the parameter in this way, unlike doing it with a client in PHP that the way to send the parameter would be `'numbers' => array (1, 2, 3)` and works correctly .

Comment: Side note - why not use `return array_sum($numbers);` instead your function?

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know that function, I'm not familiar with PHP but I'll implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem, I leave it here in case someone else is useful, the first mistake I made was to declare the input parameter as a whole `xsd:int`, so what I did was declare it as `SOAP-ENC:Array` on the server in PHP:

```
$server->register(
        'Suma',
        array('numbers' => 'SOAP-ENC:Array'),
        array('return' => 'xsd:int'),
        $ns
    );
```

Now in the Python client I used the `factory.create()` method of the suds client to declare a variable with the type `SOAP-ENC:Array`

```
from suds.client import Client

def wsarchivo():
    client = Client("http://localhost/PracticaSumaArray/server.php?wsdl")
    request = client.factory.create('SOAP-ENC:Array')
    request.numbers = [1,2,3]
    res = client.service.Suma(request)
    print(res)

wsarchivo()
```

When executing:

```
Output:
6
```